# Symfony upload large files

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I'm developing an Symfony3 website and i need to upload large files (up to 2GB) to server from UI.

I tried using [FileManagerBundle](https://github.com/artgris/FileManagerBundle), but got errors with file size upload and memory limit. Increasing upload_max_filesize and memory_limit in php.ini didn't help me.

Can anybody help with this? How can I implement this?

Comment: You need to upload your file by chunks, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011138/handling-pluploads-chunked-uploads-on-the-server-side) - may help

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far?

Comment: Might be anybody can advice me an Symfony3 Bundle or smth. like this which will help me solve my problem.